# Tkinter exception

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a project in Tkinter about 6 months ago, a teacher review it that time and he said it is good, without bugs. It could be run without any problem and worked well, but when I tried (today) to run it again i keep getting an exception:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 693, in dev_from_name
    return next(iface for iface in six.itervalues(self)
StopIteration
```

I wanted to post the project on github so I downloaded it from the mail that I sent to the teacher at that time.
Have been any major changes to Tkinter lately that I dont know about, I have Python 3.8 and Tkinter 0.1.0?

Comment: How have you decided that you have Tkinter 0.1.0? You should have version 8.5 or 8.6.

Comment: I dont know, I just installed it from cmd and it installed 0.1.0. I tried to update it but it said that the version is good. I will try to force update it.

Comment: How did you "install it from cmd"? You can't normally install tkinter from a command prompt.

Comment: The error is coming from `scapy`, anyway - the only connection to Tkinter is that the problematic code is being called from a Tkinter button click or other event handler.

Comment: `tkinter` is installed with `Python` and you don't have to install - and maybe you installed something different with the similar name. Error shows path `...\site-packages\scapy\...` which shows that it is problem with module `scapy`. Maybe 6 month ago you was using older modules and new version may have some bug or changes which may need changes in your code.

Comment: You have installed a module named `tk` which is `TensorKit`, not `tkinter`.  `tkinter` cannot be installed using `pip` as said by others.